# Angular2 - Displaying values in a Select item

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm pretty new to Angular/WebDev (I come from a mobile background), so do bear with me here...

I'm trying to display state abbreviations in a "Select" menu item. I have a `client-detail-componenet.ts` file, which is where I have an array of the state abbreviations:

```
export class ClientDetailComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
private showDebugInfo: boolean;
private clientDataFG: FormGroup;
private clientDataFGFormVal: AppFormValidationResult;
private brapClient: BrapClient;

//TODO - this should be created somewhere else...
states = ['AL', 'AK', 'AS', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE', 'DC', 'FM', 'FL', 'GA', 'GU', 'HI', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'IA', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'ME', 'MH', 'MD', 'MA', 'MI', 'MN', 'MS', 'MO', 'MT', 'NE', 'NV', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NY', 'NC', 'ND', 'MP', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PW', 'PA', 'PR', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VT', 'VI', 'VA', 'WA', 'WV', 'WI', 'WY'];
...
}
```

In the corresponding HTML file, I have the following code where I intend to put a dropdown selector inside of a form:

```
            <div class="field-area">

                <label for="state" class="text-center">State</label>
                <!--<div class="field state">
                    <input type="text" id="addressState" class="form-control" formControlName="addressState">
                </div>-->

                <select class="form-control" formControlName="state">
                  <option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state">{{states}}</option>
                </select>
              </div>
```

Some part of this is incorrect, as when I run the project and look at the menu, no option-values are shown in the selector. Can anyone help me understand what I need to do? Thanks!

**EDIT** As Alexander pointed out, there was a typo in the HTML file...the corrected line is below:

`<option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state">{{state}}</option>`

However, I'm still not seeing any values show up in the selector:
[image]

**EDIT 2**

This is where the form group + it's elements are created:

```
// This creates the initial form for the page, as well as the validation objects.
createForm() {
    this.clientDataFG = this.fb.group({
        firstName: [null, Validators.required],
        lastName: [null, Validators.required],
        emailAddress: [null],
        homePhone: [null],
        addressStreet1: [null],
        addressCity: [null],
        addressState: [null],
        addressZip: [null],
        weight: [null],
        height: [null],
        riderType: [null],
        clientBikes: this.fb.array([]), // <-- clientBikes is as an empty FormArray

    });
```

Comment: Are you initializing each from FormControl, including `state`, via something like FormBuilder?

Comment: As you can see in this plunk: https://embed.plnkr.co/s2quKKVhsYm0NTL6k9Ib/, there are no errors in the *ngFor syntax, so the problem lies elsewhere. Try including your FormControl code + CSS and maybe we can better help.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky thanks; that makes sense - I added another edit to the question w/that code

Comment: You are initializing a FormControl identified as `addressState`, but are using `state` in the template. Try changing to `formControlName="addressState"`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `<option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state">{{states}}</option>` you have `{{states}}`  with a trailing "s" character rather than just `{{state}}`.

Try removing the trailing "s" to display/target the current iteration's `state` string value.

```
<option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state">{{state}}</option>
```

Make sure you are initializing each FormControl via something like [FormBuilder](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#introduction-to-formbuilder) in the constructor:

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

export class ClientDetailComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    states: string[] = ['AL'];

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.clientDataFG = this.fb.group({
            state: 'AL'
        });
    }
}
```

You are initializing a FormControl identified as `addressState`, but are using `state` in the template. Try changing `formControlName="state"` to `formControlName="addressState"`.

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="addressState">
    <option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state">{{state}}</option>
</select>
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Hey Alexander, thanks for the typo catch - it's still behaving weird. I'll update my answer though (with a screenshot and this typo fix).